# Desenvolvimento ágil e atualização da documentação

Tags: engenharia-de-software, uml, documentação, metodologia-ágil, scrum

Levando em consideração a segunda premissa do manifesto ágil:

“**Software em funcionamento** mais que documentação abrangente”

Conforme as práticas ágeis, scrum, XP, etc..., se durante o desenvolvimento, após termos feito o desenho UML das classes, verificarmos a necessidade de criar um atributo novo para uma das classes devemos programar o atributo em nossa classe e banco de dados após e atualizamos a UML? Ou deixamos o desenho UML para traz e seguimos planejando as iterações?

Lembrando que metodologias ágeis não descartam documentação, mas gostaria de saber até qual ponto trabalhamos em conjunto com ela.

Answer (score 8):

## A questão é...

> Quando sua equipe faz reunião ou você discute alguma funcionalidade com um colega desenvolvedor, você usa os diagramas?

Em caso **afirmativo**, então o uso deve ser cotidiano, portanto **é recompensador** o trabalho de manter a documentação atualizada.

Em caso **negativo**, provavelmente os diagramas foram feitos apenas para um entendimento inicial ou para cumprir uma expectativa do cliente ou da gerência, logo **não vale a pena**, pois o trabalho é mais que o benefício colhido.

## Considerações

Se o arquivo-fonte dos diagramas é versionado junto com o código-fonte, então é fácil que qualquer membro da equipe atualize o diagrama e sincronize o projeto com o SCM.

Por outro lado, se a equipe costuma trabalhar com documentos impressos, simplesmente risque o documento a lápis e será suficiente para usar nos próximos *sprints* (desde, é claro, que ninguém brinque de basquete com os papéis e um cesto de lixo).

Diagramas UML não precisam ser um reflexo 100% preciso do código. Em muitos casos, evito colocar atributos em classes para não comprometer a estrutura interna.

Mas o que ocorre frequentemente é usar a UML para representar o modelo de banco de dados do sistema. Não concordo muito com isso. Existem ferramentas mais adequadas que permitem fazer um MER (Modelo Entidade-Relacionamento) e já sincronizar o diagrama com o banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

O meio mais fácil (e barato) seria fazer as alterções nas classes (software em funcionamento primeiro) e depois fazer a engenharia reversa dela para gerar diagramas de classes e afins. Há várias ferramentas no mercado que fazem isso pra você.

Acho que cabe aqui apontar algo para reflexão que já foi descrito em vários artigos, que [UML não é documentação](http://blog.aspercom.com.br/2008/06/06/uml-nao-eh-documentacao/).

Comment: Apesar do título do artigo citado (não tenho o artigo completo), nenhuma das fontes (Fowler, Ambler) sugere que UML não seja documentação. Pelo contrário: *Again the UML is useful here, providing the diagrams are selective to help communication.*

Comment: Sem dúvidas ela ajuda a comunicar, mas isso não implica em ser documentação. Isso está descrito no artigo linkado.

Comment: O que estou dizendo é que as fontes que o artigo linkado cita não comprovam a ideia passada, nem o autor fornece uma definição apropriada de *documentação*. Aliás, a definição padrão da documentação segundo os principais autores de Engenharia de Software envolve justamente a *comunicação*, então ou o autor quis ser um tanto polêmico, ou ele usou uma definição alternativa de documentação.

Answer (score 1):

No conceito de desenvolvimento "ágil" a documentação é um mero coadjuvante no processo (user story é um ótimo exemplo).

Se você está no "ágil" a ideia é que a documentação seja colaborativa, ou seja, ela vai crescendo de acordo com a necessidade e com a colaboração de todos após interações da equipe (daily scrum ou sprint planing por exemplo).

O importante é entregar valor ao cliente. Se a documentação é um artefato a ser entregue também, fatalmente você terá que atualiza-la, mas não necessariamente no exato momento em que foi identificada uma alteração.

Se a mudança impactará nas próximas sprints, então é interessante que você faça a atualização na documentação.

Agora, se a documentação não é um artefato entregável e se as mudanças não impactarem no que ainda será desenvolvido, sugiro toma-la apenas como lição aprendida.

Lembre-se que o foco na metodologia ágil é entregar valor ao cliente. Por isso eles não abordam documentação, apesar de que a documentação pode sim ser um entregável que gere valor.

Faça seu próprio julgamento.